PySpark Extract String JSON data into multiple Rows
I have the following PySpark DataFrame. I need to extract JSON data stored as strings within a column in my DataFrame, and subsequently create multiple rows based on the extracted data in PySpark.
Example Input:



response (string column)




{"Customer Data": [{"id": "5", "name": "Jony"}, {"id": "10", "name": "Jems"}]}



Expected output:



id (int)
name (string)




5
Jony


10
Jems



Any ideas how to do this?

not an exact answer but you can use ideas from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78292935/3238085

Hope this fits your needs:
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    Row(response='{"Customer Data": [{"id": "5", "name": "Jony"}, {"id": "10", "name": "Jems"}]}'),
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField(name="response", dataType=StringType())
])

json_schema = StructType([
    StructField(
        name="Customer Data", 
        dataType=ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField(name="id", dataType=StringType()),
                StructField(name="name", dataType=StringType())
            ])
        )
    ),
])

df = (
    spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
    .withColumn("parsed_json", f.from_json("response", schema=json_schema))
    .selectExpr("parsed_json.*")
    .withColumn("CustomerDataExploded", f.explode("Customer Data"))
    .select("CustomerDataExploded.*")
    .withColumn("id", f.col("id").cast(IntegerType()))
)

df.show()

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  5|Jony|
| 10|Jems|
+---+----+


